# String Parser in Lucene

Tags: java, parsing, lucene

I am new in Lucene Search,

I merged DrillDownQuery and Boolean Query in such a way like

```
BooleanQuery inner=new BooleanQuery();
inner.add(NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("year",null,null, false, false));

DrillDownQuery q = new DrillDownQuery(config);
q.add("book","lucene in action","lissa" );
inner.add(q,Occur.MUST)


DrillDownQuery q1 = new DrillDownQuery(config);
q1.add("book","java programming","hills publications" );
inner.add(q1,Occur.MUST)
```

i just want to store the above Query in Database as a string 
so that I can use it

```
String str=inner.toString();
```

the str variable contains this type of value

```
 ++ConstantScore($facets:booklucene in actionlissa)^0.0 ++ConstantScore($facets:bookjava programminghills publications)^0.0 +year:{* TO *}
```

as in future whenever any user clicks on link, I just want to fetch this string query from database  and get parse into Lucene Query

for this purpose i  used lots of parser but am not able to parse such type of query. Some of the parser I am using is here

```
QueryParser qs=new QueryParser(null,new WhitespaceAnalyzer());
   Query q= qs.parse(str)
```

I have also use ComplexPhraseQueryParser,SimpleParser but I am not getting proper result yet

any kind of help would be heartily appreciated